# Why is Python saying these two fractions are the same?

Tags: python

I'm trying to take advantage of Python's nearly infinite integer precision in order to work with large fractions, but there seem to be some precision issues creeping in anyway.

I have a class called Fraction, which has a numerator attribute and a denominator attribute. I then defined the arithmetic operations on the class using only addition/subtraction and multiplication of integer components. The idea is that there will never be any precision loss due to floating point issues. The initializer method and subtraction method are shown below

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator = 1):
        self.numerator = numerator/GCD(numerator,denominator)
        self.denominator = denominator/GCD(numerator,denominator)

    def __sub__(self,other):
        print("x:",int(self.denominator))
        print("y:",int(other.numerator))
        print("x*y:",int(self.denominator*other.numerator))
        return Fraction(self.numerator*other.denominator - self.denominator*other.numerator, self.denominator*other.denominator)
```

The `print` statements were added for debugging purposes, and they highlight the issue.

When I run the program in python3.6.1, the following issues develop when I start performing operations in the terminal:

Python Shell Input:

`Fraction(1,29) - Fraction(7924325834608857,229805449203656864)`

Output:

```
x: 29
y: 7924325834608857
x*y: 229805449203656864
(0/1)
```

The problem is that `29*7924325834608857` does not equal `229805449203656864`

So what's going on?

EDIT in response to comments:
Here is the GCD function I used. It has worked for every test case I tried it on, but maybe the precision issue is with python's modulus operator?

```
def GCD(num1,num2):
    a = max(num1,num2)
    b = min(num1,num2)

    if a == 0 and b != 0:
        return b
    elif b == 0 and a !=0:
        return a
    elif a%b == 0:
        return b
    else:
        return GCD(a%b, b)
```

Comment: Is this python 2 or python 3? In python 3 "//" is the integer division operator.

Comment: There are some issues, I assume GCD is an alias to `math.gcd`? It's arguments must be integers, but the division you make in __init__ always gives a flioat. As @JamesKPolk said, make a floor division with `//` to fix that.

Comment: Are you sure `GCD` works?

Comment: @Talon He would be getting a TypeError if that were the problem, so he must be using a different GCD function.

Comment: `numerator/GCD(numerator,denominator)` will make your `.numerator` a `float` object. Same issue with your denominator.

Comment: Get rid of those `int()`s in `__sub__()` - they're hiding the fact that your numerator or denominator became a float.

Comment: As an aside, you know Python has a `Fraction` type in the standard library? It's available in [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fractions.html)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I did not know that, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the incorrect calculation appears to be a float rounding issue. Because in `__init__`, you have a division operation, which returns a float, so the following calculations work with floats as well, and there, rounding issues might appear. You do cast to int in `__sub__`, but after the calculation took place. To test, try:

```py
29 * 7924325834608857.0
29 * 7924325834608857
29 * 7924325834608857.0 == 29 * 7924325834608857
```

Results will be

```py
2.2980544920365686e+17
229805449203656853
False
```

To fix this, you could make a floor division (Which ignores the remainder of a division, making the result an int) in `__init__`, like this

```py
class Fraction():
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator=1):
        self.numerator = numerator // GCD(numerator, denominator)
        self.denominator = denominator // GCD(numerator, denominator)
```

Comment: This did solve the problem. Thank you. I incorrectly assumed that because GCD necessarily divided the numerator, the result would be an integer.

Comment: That was true in Python 2; `/` only returned a float if one of its arguments was a float.